# XML Deserialization inside class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I tried XML serialization the first time. The following code works as expected, but I don't like to use this "copyFrom" method.

Is there a better way that keeps the save and load methods inside the class itself?

```
namespace Test
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Settings
    {
        public struct Connection
        {
            [XmlAttribute ("user")]
            public string sUser;

            [XmlAttribute ("domain")]
            public string sDomain;
        }

        public Connection connection;

        public Settings ()
        {
            connection.sUser = "";
            connection.sDomain = "";
        }

        internal void loadFromFile ()
        {
            if (File.Exists (Constants.STORAGE_SETTINGS_FILE))
            {
                using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream (Constants.STORAGE_SETTINGS_FILE, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    copyFrom ((Settings)new XmlSerializer (typeof (Settings)).Deserialize (filestream));
                }
            }
        }

        internal void saveToFile ()
        {
            using (StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter (Constants.STORAGE_SETTINGS_FILE))
            {
                new XmlSerializer (typeof (Settings)).Serialize (streamwriter, this);
            }
        }

        internal void copyFrom (Settings settings)
        {
            connection.sUser = settings.connection.sUser;
            connection.sDomain = settings.connection.sDomain;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. They belong to the class, or do you mean another class?

Comment: I'd like to avoid the "copyFrom" and assign the loaded values directly to the member variables.

Comment: The serialize results returns a class and you either need code to move properties to this.sUser and this.sDomain or make these variable static.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `copyFrom` method.

In the `loadFromFile` method, you can write

```
connection = ((Settings)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings)).Deserialize(filestream)).connection;
```

Also note that the `Serializable` attribute not needed for XML serialization. Remove it.

Comment: This works for the "connection" structure, but is there also a way that works for the whole serialized object? I'm looking for something like "this = (Settings)new XmlSerializer (typeof (Settings)).Deserialize (filestream)". This doesn't work of cause because "this" is read-only. I just don't want to list the serialized members (the two strings for the moment, but there will be more soon) again.

Comment: @André - Change the design of your app. The object must not save/load himself. Do it at a higher level.